# python pandas calculating hours for daterange in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date-range

I want to calculate oncall hours for date range. The standard oncall hours is 16 hours for each day from Monday to Friday and 24 hours for Saturday and Sunday.

I've already written the code, which works for two specific dates:

```
date1 = date(2017,4, 13)
date2 = date(2017,4, 17)

def daterange(d1, d2):
     return (d1 + datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in range((d2 - d1).days + 1))

total = 0
for n in daterange(date1, date2):
    if n.weekday() < 5:
        total += 16
    else: 
        total += 24
print (total)
```

I have a problem with implementing this to Date Range:

```
Start      End
2017-02-03 2017-03-15
2017-02-05 2017-03-16
2017-02-06 2017-03-17
2017-02-10 2017-03-18
...        ...
```

type of these columns above is datetime64[ns]

and the error is TypeError: cannot convert the series to class 'int'

is any way to calculate this for time series column? It can be in a new column or just in results

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom function with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x : np.where(pd.date_range(x['Start'], x['End']).weekday < 5, 16, 24).sum(), axis=1)
print (df)
       Start        End  new
0 2017-02-03 2017-03-15  752
1 2017-02-05 2017-03-16  728
2 2017-02-06 2017-03-17  720
3 2017-02-10 2017-03-18  680
```

It is same as:

- create range with [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) from both dates
- then get [`weekday`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.weekday.html)
- then get hours by [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) by condition and last `sum`

---

```
def f(x):
    b = pd.date_range(x['Start'], x['End']).weekday
    return np.where(b < 5, 16, 24).sum()

df['new'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
print (df)
       Start        End  new
0 2017-02-03 2017-03-15  752
1 2017-02-05 2017-03-16  728
2 2017-02-06 2017-03-17  720
3 2017-02-10 2017-03-18  680
```

Another solution, but I think it is more complicated:

```
#reshape df
df1 = df.stack().reset_index()
df1.columns = ['i','c','date']
#groupby by index and resample to days, forward fill NaNs
df1 = df1.set_index('date').groupby('i').resample('D').ffill()
         .reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index()
#get hours
df1['tot'] = np.where(df1['date'].dt.weekday < 5, 16, 24)
#sum by index
s = df1.groupby('i')['tot'].sum()
#join to original
df = df.join(s)
print (df.head(10))
       Start        End  tot
0 2017-02-03 2017-03-15  752
1 2017-02-05 2017-03-16  728
2 2017-02-06 2017-03-17  720
3 2017-02-10 2017-03-18  680
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*100).reset_index(drop=True) 
print (df)

def f(df):
    df1 = df.stack().reset_index()
    df1.columns = ['i','c','date']
    df1 = df1.set_index('date').groupby('i').resample('D').ffill().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index()
    df1['tot'] = np.where(df1['date'].dt.weekday < 5, 16, 24)
    s = df1.groupby('i')['tot'].sum()
    return df.join(s)

print (f(df))
mapping = {i:16 if i<5 else 24 for i in range(7)}

In [190]: %timeit (f(df))
1 loop, best of 3: 482 ms per loop

#MaxU solution
In [191]: %timeit df['oncall_hours'] =  df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['Start'], x['End']).to_series().dt.weekday.map(mapping).sum(), axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 531 ms per loop

In [192]: %timeit df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x : np.where(pd.date_range(x['Start'], x['End']).weekday < 5, 16, 24).sum(), axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 166 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can use the following simple mapping:

sample series:

```
In [110]: s = pd.date_range('2017-01-01', periods=10).to_series()

In [111]: s
Out[111]:
2017-01-01   2017-01-01
2017-01-02   2017-01-02
2017-01-03   2017-01-03
2017-01-04   2017-01-04
2017-01-05   2017-01-05
2017-01-06   2017-01-06
2017-01-07   2017-01-07
2017-01-08   2017-01-08
2017-01-09   2017-01-09
2017-01-10   2017-01-10
Freq: D, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

mapping

```
# DateLikeSeries.dt.weekday returns the day of the week with Monday=0, Sunday=6
In [94]: mapping = {i:16 if i<5 else 24 for i in range(7)}

In [95]: mapping
Out[95]: {0: 16, 1: 16, 2: 16, 3: 16, 4: 16, 5: 24, 6: 24}

In [112]: s.dt.weekday.map(mapping)
Out[112]:
2017-01-01    24
2017-01-02    16
2017-01-03    16
2017-01-04    16
2017-01-05    16
2017-01-06    16
2017-01-07    24
2017-01-08    24
2017-01-09    16
2017-01-10    16
Freq: D, dtype: int64


In [113]: s.dt.weekday.map(mapping).sum()
Out[113]: 184
```

you can apply this logic to your DataFrame:

```
In [107]: df
Out[107]:
       Start        End
0 2017-02-03 2017-03-15
1 2017-02-05 2017-03-16
2 2017-02-06 2017-03-17
3 2017-02-10 2017-03-18

In [108]: %paste
df['oncall_hours'] = \
    df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['Start'], x['End'])
                         .to_series()
                         .dt.weekday
                         .map(mapping)
                         .sum(),
             axis=1)
## -- End pasted text --

In [109]: df
Out[109]:
       Start        End  oncall_hours
0 2017-02-03 2017-03-15           752
1 2017-02-05 2017-03-16           728
2 2017-02-06 2017-03-17           720
3 2017-02-10 2017-03-18           680
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the apply function to do this. The error just tells you that you are not calling the function properly.

In pandas the apply method applies a function to every row of the dataframe(row by row)

Change your pandas dataframe function call to:

```
df['new_column'] = df.apply( lambda x : daterange(x['start'],x['end']))
```

Let me know if you need further help.